# On $G$-gerbes over the punctured disk

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, stacks, complex-manifolds, gerbes

Let $G$ be a finite (not necessarily abelian) group and let $\mathcal{X}\to D^*$ be a $G$-gerbe over the punctured disk $D^*$.

Is there a finite etale cover $D^*\to \mathcal{X}$?

I think of $G$-gerbes as higher analogues of $G$-torsors. If $X\to D^*$ is a $G$-torsor, then $X$ is in fact isomorphic to $D^*$ and the morphism $X\to D^*$ is given by $z\mapsto z^e$ for some $e\geq 1$. Is there a similar picture for $G$-gerbes?

(I should stress that I assume $\mathcal X$ and $X$ to be connected.)

Comment: Are there any nontrivial gerbes over $D^*$ at all? (For $G$ abelian there are none)

Comment: I thought that there were non-trivial $G$-gerbes, as there are non-trivial $G$-torsors. Maybe my expectation was too naive?

Comment: Torsors under $G$ correspond to $H^1(D^*, G) = {\rm Hom}(\pi_1(D^*), G) = G$, while gerbes correspond to $H^2(D^*, G)$, which is zero (at least for abelian groups).

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Let $L$ be a band. (These are classified by $H^1(D^*,Out(G))$, so this set can be non-trivial. Take for example a group $G$ with $Out(G) = \mu_n$.) The set of $G$-gerbes with band $L$ is (when non-empty) a torsor under the trivial group $H^2(D^*,Z(G))$. The latter is trivial by your remark. So, up to the choice of a (possibly non-trivial?) band, all $G$-gerbes are trivial. Does that sound right?

Comment: @PortoVino topologically, at least, such gerbes on the punctured disk should correspond to $pi_1$ of a certain classifying space, namely the classifying space of the crossed module $\mathop{Ad}\colon G\to \mathop{Aut}(G)$. I think in this case ($G$ discrete) that $pi_1 = \mathop{Out}(G)$